# How to save a GameMaker 2 Project to a Git repo?

Tags: git, github, game-maker, gml

So, I'm an ace with git. I've used it with the CLI every single day for years to manage hundreds of software development projects. But now comes the "GameMaker 2" IDE... and it is beyond me, how the hell I'm supposed to integrate it with GitHub?

Typically, for human normal software dev projects you create the repo on GitHub, clone it locally and then save your project files to the local repo. Done. All that is needed now is to do the assorted git add, git commit, git push magic to push your code to the remote repo.

But the "GameMaker 2" IDE seems to intentionally want to prevent you from doing this. It is as if the designers sat around thinking about how best to obstruct the user from setting up a project hosted on GitHub. It is as if they don't want you sharing your files with team mates or have the ability to safely store your code online. AAAARG!

Anyway, angry ranting aside... I can save my code to the repo I've created, no problem. But when it comes to the "GameMaker 2" IDE opening up a project, it doesn't want to recognize any projects that are not default saved to the GameMaker local directory that's created on the user's computer during initial install and project creation. The same thing happens when I use the export feature to export my project to the local git repo.

Is there an invisible file or something that gets nested in a "GameMaker 2" project folder that tells the IDE that this is a real project that can be opened?

Can anyone tell me what files I need to include in a GameMaker 2 project stored in my local git repo so that the "GameMaker 2" IDE can open them? Or tell me how to effectively integrate the IDE with GitHub? This BS is seriously pissing me off. It should not be this difficult to use a standard tool like git with a premium game engine IDE!

Thanks,

Wulf

Answer (score 3):

> Typically, for human normal software dev projects you create the repo on GitHub, clone it locally and then save your project files to the local repo. Done. All that is needed now is to do the assorted git add, git commit, git push magic to push your code to the remote repo.

*Typically* you create a repo wherever, `git init` your project directory, set the remote to point at your repo, commit, and push. This still works for GameMaker. No moving files around.

> But the "GameMaker 2" IDE seems to intentionally want to prevent you from doing this. It is as if the designers sat around thinking about how best to obstruct the user from setting up a project hosted on GitHub. It is as if they don't want you sharing your files with team mates or have the ability to safely store your code online. AAAARG!

Not really, there's even a built-in plugin for git integration (see File > Preferences > Plugins > git) if you wanted those "changed file" badges in the resource tree for some reason.

> Anyway, angry ranting aside... I can save my code to the repo I've created, no problem. But when it comes to the "GameMaker 2" IDE opening up a project, it doesn't want to recognize any projects that are not default saved to the GameMaker local directory that's created on the user's computer during initial install and project creation. The same thing happens when I use the export feature to export my project to the local git repo.

Are you referring to Recent Projects list? There's an "Open" button right next to it that lets you point it at what you want to open.